# Repeating methods with string content

Tags: java, methods, iteration

I have a school assignment where I've been asked to write a program
that show a figure (a boy, girl or a rocket) in a dialog window depending
on the user's choice. 
While i've managed to do so, but one thing I can't solve.
In the assignment, the user is going to have the ability to choose how
the rocket's length is going to be by typing in a number. 
Based on the number, two of the methods I've created is going to repeat 
itself to make the rocket's length expand. But I haven't been able to come up with anything
that does this.

I've been going through various tutorials (if, while, etc.) but my limited experience with
Java has left me unsuccessful. Any ideas what to do?

```
    import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.* ;

    public class Figurer 
    {
        public static void main (String [] arg) 
        {
            String hälsning, indata ;
            char svar ;
            hälsning ="Hej!\n"
                 + "Detta program skriver ut en figur\n"
                 + "som du väljer i nästa fönster." ;
            showMessageDialog (null, hälsning) ;

    do
    {
        indata = showInputDialog ("Välj mellan följande figurer:\n"
             + "Pojke\n"
             + "Flicka\n"
             + "Raket") ;

        switch(indata) {
            case "Pojke" :
            case "pojke" :    
                String showBoy = figureBoy () ;
                showMessageDialog (null, showBoy) ;
                break;
            case "Flicka" :
            case "flicka" :    
                String showGirl = figureGirl () ;
                showMessageDialog (null, showGirl) ;
                break;
            case "Raket" :
            case "raket" :
                String showRocket = figureRocket () ;
                showMessageDialog (null, showRocket) ;
                break;

     }  
        indata = showInputDialog ("Vill du se en till figur? (j/n) ") ;   // Repetionssats för fler beräkningar
                svar = indata.charAt(0);
            }
            while (svar == 'j' || svar == 'J') ; 
            }

        //METOD: figureBoy
        //INNEHÅLL: Argument för ihopsättande av figur föreställande en pojke
        //ARGUMENT: boy, part_huvud (), part_base (), part_body () och part_cone () 
        //RETURNERAS: Sammanställningen av argumenten till variabel showBoy
        public static String figureBoy () 
        {
            String boy = part_huvud () ;  
            boy = boy + "\n" + part_base () + "\n" + part_body () + "\n"
            + part_base () + "\n" + part_cone () ;
            return boy;
        }
        //METOD: figureGirl
        //INNEHÅLL: Argument för ihopsättande av figur föreställande en flicka
        //ARGUMENT: girl, part_cone () och part_base () 
        //RETURNERAS: Sammanställningen av argumenten till variabel showGirl
        public static String figureGirl () 
        {
            String girl = part_huvud () ;  
            girl = girl + "\n" + part_cone () + "\n" + part_base () + "\n"
            + part_cone () ;
            return girl;
        }
        //METOD: figureRocket
        //INNEHÅLL: Argument för ihopsättande av figur föreställande en raket
        //ARGUMENT: rocket, part_base (), part_body () och part_cone 
        //RETURNERAS: Sammanställningen av argumenten till variabel showRocket
        public static String figureRocket () 
        {

        }
        //METOD: part_huvud
        //INNEHÅLL: Argument med tecken som föreställer ett huvud
        //ARGUMENT: Variabeln hu och sträng med tecken som formar huvudet 
        //RETURNERAS: Innehållet i variabeln hu som skickas till metoden figureBoy, figureGirl och figureRocket
        public static String part_huvud ()
        {
            String hu ;
            hu = "  /      \\ \n"
            + " |@,@| \n"
            + "  \\  v  /" ;
            return hu;
        //METOD: part_base
        //INNEHÅLL: Argument med tecken som föreställer ett tjockare streck
        //ARGUMENT: Variabeln ba och sträng med tecken som formar strecket 
        //RETURNERAS: Innehållet i variabeln ba som skickas till metoden figureBoy, figureGirl och figureRocket
        }
        public static String part_base ()
        {
            String ba ;
            ba = "=====" ;
            return ba  ;
        //METOD: part_body
        //INNEHÅLL: Argument med tecken som föreställer två paralella linjer
        //ARGUMENT: Variabeln ba och sträng med tecken som formar linjerna 
        //RETURNERAS: Innehållet i variabeln bo som skickas till metoden figureBoy, figureGirl och figureRocket    
        }
        public static String part_body ()
        {
            String bo ;
            bo = "|         |\n"
            +"|         |\n"   
            +"|         |" ;    
            return bo ;
        //METOD: part_cone
        //INNEHÅLL: Argument med tecken som föreställer en kona
        //ARGUMENT: Variabeln ba och sträng med tecken som formar konan 
        //RETURNERAS: Innehållet i variabeln co som skickas till metoden figureBoy, figureGirl och figureRocket    
        }
        public static String part_cone ()
        {
            String co ;
            co = "     /\\\n"
            +"   /    \\      \n"   
            +" /        \\       " ;    
            return co ;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not going to answer and write all the code, but here is some direction.

First, when it comes to Strings you can change to lowercase to do case-insensitive comparison:

```
indata = indata.toLowerCase();
```

That way you don't need to double all your cases and you'll match even if they uppercase the second letter by accident.  And if you ever need to do equals instead of a switch do:

```
indata.equalsIgnoreCase("some value");
```

Or even better, to avoid null:

```
"someotherstring".equalsIgnoreCase(indata);
```

Second, you can build a string of any length during a loop just as you would add numbers in a loop.  But to accomplish this use a StringBuilder object:

```
StringBuilder rocketBody = new StringBuilder();
int howmanypieces = (user input);
while (howmanypieces > 0) {

   rocketBody.append(rocketBodyPart());
   howmanypieces--;

}
rocketBody.toString();
```

Comment: That loop doesn't work in Java. It may work in C++, but not java.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an integer variable `count`, and you want to run some code `count` times, do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // code
}
```

What this does is first make a variable called `i` and initializes it to `0`, then repeats the code until `i >= count`. It also adds `1` to `i` after running the code.

Inside the loop, you can use the variable `i`. The first time the loop runs, it will be `0`. The next time it will be `1`, and so on. It will never be equal to `count`. In the last iteration, it will be `count - 1`.